# C# Socket Abstraction/Framemork with event support

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm looking for something that hides the details of sockets and provide a more typical .NET interface. I looked at SuperSocket and WCF but I'm looking for something more lightweight.

One thing I want is to be able to send an event to all the clients that have connected to the socket (or connected and requested to listen to that event), for example

```
// client code...
socketServer.connect("192.168.1.15", 5008);
socketServer.PostMessage("hello");
socketServer.SomethingHappened += clientHandler;
```

A native client should be able to use without .NET also but would need to implement details. Is there something like this available? What would be a good strategy for supporting this style of events?

Comment: Are you open to rolling your own ? I can give chunks of my socket server & client code. I assume an event will be serialized into some kind of message, then the client received message and can construct an event to be consumed ?

Comment: I prefer not to roll my own but will if needed. Actually I really just need one event which is an arbitrary string (but if a little smarter could be JSON and split off the commands more like I showed in example).

Comment: Did you ever end up finding something that does this? I'm also trying to avoid rolling my own!

Comment: No, I ended up rolling my own. I simplified it somewhat to have server always broadcasts to all clients.